# PostgreSQL: how to fetch previous insert timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

Suppose that I have table

```
create table foo (
    insert_current timestamp default now(),
    insert_previous timestamp,
    bar int primary key,
    baz varchar(10)
);
```

The data will be replaced now and then when fresh batch arrived. I would like to keep track on when previous batch was inserted as well as current timestamp. What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a trigger that automatically sets insert_current and insert_previous on UPDATE statements.

First, create the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_update() RETURNS "trigger"
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.insert_previous := OLD.insert_current;
    NEW.insert_current := NOW();
    return NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then add the trigger to your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER do_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE do_update();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you update a row, copy the value of `insert_current` to `insert_previous` and set `insert_current` to the current timestamp:

```
UPDATE foo
   SET baz = 'whatever',
       insert_previous = insert_current,
       insert_current  = NOW()
 WHERE bar = 1;
```